# How can i go higher than the frequency limit set on EQ band 6 automation in davinci resolve

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve, automation, equalization

Very new to audio stuff so sorry if i get some terms wrong in advance.

I'm using automation to keyframe the frequency on band 6 in the EQ as shown here

[image: Automation on the clip]

Even when it hits the bottom, i still dont feel its enough. Band 6 seems to have a frequency limit (automation wise) that changes depending on the starting point of the band. This image shows what i want automation to keep doing but it wont. i start it at 20k6 and it stops at 1k4 for some reason.

[image: What i want to keep doing]

I can move the band before hand to get a lower frequency but that also effects the starting point. **My goal is to get a stronger muffle effect at the end by automating the 6th band to go lower while keeping the same starting point.** Please let me know if there is a better way to get this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's in the manual…page 3300 (yeah, ikr, it's a big manual, but it is searchable;)

Im trying to do this without having to launch DaVinci, as my machine is currently editing another huge project in a different app.

Each of the bands will have a highest & lowest frequency it can reach. Try maybe the middle band. Set it to hi-shelf [which is not quite the same as hi-pass, but should be OK for this]. If it will reach even 12k it's probably high enough to start.
Dial in a negative gain - you can automate this too.
You can change the slope with the Q dial.
Then automate reducing the frequency over the period you need the sound to get duller.

With a little fiddling, you ought to be able to get what you want, with only a maximum of 6 parameter points in your automation.